# Final Fantasy a realm reborn (PS3) - downloading update and launcher problems

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I bought the game and followed installation instructions only to enter a world of crap and confusion. After registering the code I was taken to a download page with a download requirement of almost 7 hours !!!.  First problem is that this is outside the PS3 maximum powersave timeout limit so the console shuts down before it can download. The instructions and the loadstone guide give no information or make any reference to this massive download requirement. Square Enix support is none existent as they seem to do all they can to avoid interfacing with their customers and I can get no sensible replies to questions to them. While trying to download this massive data, I get error messages saying I need to register the code - which I obviously have done and received confirmation of this. I also get message saying I cant proceed as I need to also be connected to PSN but am already logged on to PSN - MY console is set to sign in automatically. Considering the fact that this is a subscription based game and only a limited number of days are included in the purchase, I have already wasted two days of that limited time just trying to start the game. As all official help options seem to be totally useless and evasive of issues and there is no sensible help option like being able to actually speak to someone, I would welcome any help, information, assistance, clarification about these problems and how to actually be able to start playing the game. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your best bet is to actually post this to Reddit. You'll have a much higher chance of encountering someone there who has come into the same issue and can give you the exact steps to solve it. http://www.reddit.com/r/ffxiv

Comment: PSN is apparently undergoing some problems at the moment which might be having an impact.